# Git alias command for add/commit/push with multiple inputs

Tags: git, bash, alias, git-bash

I want to have an alias which lets you add a file, commit and push it.

I started off with this:

```
[alias]
    acp = "!f() { git add $1; }; f"
```

But whenever I put in an input, I get a file not found error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'test.txt' did not match any files
```

Ideally I want to be able to write:

```
git acp 'myfile.txt' 'my commit message'
```

I have this working, but I can't make it work with an input for add:

```
acp2 = "!f() { git add --all; git commit -m \"${1:-commit}\"; git push origin master; }; f"
```

Comment: What is not working when you have an input argument for add? Changing `--all` to `$1` and `${1:-commit}` to `${2:-commit}` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
[alias]
acp = "!f() { git add \"$1\"; git commit -m \"${2:-commit}\"; git push origin master; }; f"
```

This should be enough to work with your syntax:

```
git acp 'myfile.txt' 'my commit message'
```

I tested this as follows:

```
$ echo>test
$ git acp test "the message"
[master 9b81eb2] the message
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test

$ cat .git/config
...
[alias]
    acp = "!f() { git add \"$1\"; git commit -m \"${2:-commit}\"; }; f"
$
```

Comment: I still get the same error. The file is definitely in the directory.

Comment: Running the same version. I can't even get `acp = "!f() { git add \"$1\"; }; f"` to work.

Comment: And this is in `.git/config`, and your current working directory is the project root directory?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Running the shortened version above without any input doesn't yield anything if that helps.